# Unable to perform the action on android webview

Tags: android-webview, appium, robotframework, appium-android

I am using Robot Framework with python. I have a page that has a web view. I am able to find the element through Appium inspector and also through the Chrome Dev tools. But those locators are not working. The test case passes but it does not click on that element.

Is there any work around for this issue?

Comment: I have found the solution myself.  You just need to change the native app context to webview context. 
   Switch to context    WEBVIEW_blabla

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the class name locator?

`driver.find_element_by_class_name()`